# Inner join not returning desired result

Tags: sql-server, filter, inner-join, where-clause

I am querying my data with the following query:

```
  Select  
  Convert(varchar(50),PE.dateofstay,103) 'Date of Stay',  
  C.embossname 'EmbossName',  
  PE.pastexperience,  
  U.UserName ,  
  M.merchantname1   
  from card C   
 inner join PastExperience PE on c.EmbossLine=PE.embossline   
 inner join Users U on U.UserId=PE.userid  
 inner join Merchant M on M.MerchantID=U.MerchantID  
    where C.Embossline = '02563987' 
-- and (C.EmbossName Like '%DANIEL MWANGALA%' )
 AND(PE.dateofstay>='2013-11-03 00:00:00.000' and PE.dateofstay<='2015-11-03 00:00:00.000')
```

Problem is when I filter it with `EmbossLine` I get the desired result but when I am trying to filter it with `EmbossName` (I have commented that out over here)
I dont get anything? I am so stuck with this? Why is this happening?

Comment: Provide sample data.

Comment: Are you sure you get EmbossName like `DANIEL MWANGALA` not for example `DANIEL <multiple_spaces_or_tab>  MWANGALA`. Also it is very bad practise to search `LIKE '%phrase%' `because it is not SARG-able

Comment: There is nothing syntactically wrong with that query. We need to see your data to find out why a card with that EmbossName isn't returned.

Comment: are you sure you have record where `EmbossName` contains **DANIEL MWANGALA**

Comment: Also your title is misleading

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: your database does not have any records that match all four of your `WHERE` clause criteria.

What you can do:
You've already isolated `EmbossName` as a problem child, now you need to see why the particular record(s) you're trying to return don't match the format you originally specified. Try making the search simpler, something like:

```
WHERE C.Embossline = '02563987' 
AND C.EmbossName LIKE '%DAN%'
AND PE.dateofstay >= '2013-11-03 00:00:00.000'
AND PE.dateofstay <= '2015-11-03 00:00:00.000'
```

If that works you can step it up to something more specific like

```
AND C.EmbossName LIKE '%DANIEL%MWANGALA%'
```

If that fails, find just the `EmbossName` record (without all the other joined info from this query) that you are certain should match and then copy and paste that value into a text editor to look for additional characters etc that may be less noticeable in formatted GUIs.

One or more of your `INNER JOIN` criteria may also pose a problem - if this Daniel fellow exists in `C` but doesn't have any corresponding data in the other tables you joined then no results will show. Try changing some of those `INNER JOINs` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and see if you get any results. If you get some rows with `NULL` values in the joined columns then there is a strong possibility that you joined tables that don't have any corresponding records for this individual.